# WPCLI search and replace in a particlar site dir effect another site-dir

Tags: database, mysql, wp-cli, backup, customization

In /var/www/html I have a site dir. I've duplicated that site's dir and db into a new site dir and db by the name of "test" (without quote marks), and changed `wp-config.php` accordingly.

I Navigated into this new site dir in console (`cd /var/www/html/test`), and ran:

```
wp search-replace 'https://MY_ORIGIAL_DOMAIN' 'https://MY_IP/test'
```

The site itself goes up and its internal links become based on `test`, but 2 problems occur:

1. All css is jumbeled up.
2. The original site's CSS is also jumbeled up (this is quite wired, I must say).

While I can reverse the result, I admit I don't understand what's going on (because I do everything in the new dir and not in the original dir).

### Update

I was wrong, the db wasn't changed to `test` in `wp-config.php`... It seems my sed operation failed:

```
sed -i 's/${domain}/test'/g /var/www/html/test/wp-config.php
```

Comment: lots of questions: were the 2 new directories nested or side-by-side.  Did you change the wp-config?  did you try logging the change or at least reporting with wp-cli?

Comment: To make sure I'm totally clear, I've edited the question. I would most appreciate if you'd read it again in this more detailed manner.

Comment: try this:  "wp db size" and confirm the db is correct, then also try getting a report, or run a "dry run" of the search replace to see if it's trying to change both db's.  put results in question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to some conflict between variable values (I don't recall the exact details).

The solution AFAIR, was to just use another Bash session, without any predefined variables (I just newly defined any variable I needed this time):

```
$ bash
```